# Marshalled struct results in OutOfBoundsException in C#

Tags: c#, exception, struct, marshalling, outofrangeexception

So I have made a struct that I want to send around using a simple DatagramSocket.

The struct code is as follows:

```
 public struct MsgData
{
    private readonly int _value;
    private readonly string _descr;
    public MsgData(string desc, int value)
    {
        _descr = desc;
        _value = value;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public string GetDescr()
    {
        return _descr;
    }
}
```

I proceed by converting to a byte array like so:

```
 public static byte[] GetBytes(MsgData message)
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(message);
        var data = new byte[size];

        System.IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(message, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return data;
    }
```

and return it to a MsgData struct like so:

```
public static MsgData GetMessage(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var data = new MsgData();

        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(data);
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);

        data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MsgData>(ptr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return data;
    }
```

However I get a:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Requested range extends past the end of the array.'
```

when trying to convert on line:

```
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);
```

I'm going to go with a simple Serialization instad now but I wonder why this doesn't work as expected?

Comment: What is `bytes.Length` when the exception occurs?

Comment: Are you sure that `bytes` contains enough bytes? I would add `if (bytes.Length != size) throw new ArgumentException();` somewhere.

Comment: It isn't clear what you intend this code to do. First you haven't specified StructLayout attribute on the struct, in which case packing is unspecified (you can detect which packing will be used depending on x86/x64 but code as stands look brittle). Additionally, you're not specifying "MarshalAs" attributes on your fields, in which case your string won't really be marshalled. Lastly, you're passing "true" to StructureToPtr's fDeleteOld parameter but your allocated memory should not contain a structure by default.

Comment: Please explain what you want to accomplish instead of just "this code fails, why"

Comment: `var size = Marshal.SizeOf(data);` <= that's wrong!

Comment: "simple serialization", to be honest there is no such thing. Either you write it simple, in which case you can't make it general (ie. it can't take just any object) or you make it general in which case it can't be simple (it will need to handle a lot of cornercases).

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf(data)` is wrong insofar as the structure is not ready for marshalling. If you apply structlayout attribute and marshalas attributes, it will report the size you have decided it should have.

Comment: bytes.Length reports 8. the size variable reports 16. Sounds like I'm missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Because you measure the size of an emtpy struct element. I don't get why you do that in the first place. You can send it around without all that marshalling fuzz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code so let me explain what you need to do in order to fix it.

First, your structure has a layout that is optimized for quick memory access. When marshalling this into a byte array you're going to, by default, copy that memory layout.

Your `Marshal.SizeOf(...)` call reflects this. It returns 16, always. How can that be? How can your string be marshalled to something inside these 16 bytes, even if the string is much longer than 16?

The answer is that it doesn't. Instead you're marshalling the pointer to the string object as bytes.

16 bytes is 8 bytes for the int (4 for the int + 4 for padding to align the next value on a 8-byte memory address boundary, I'm running 64-bit), and then 8 bytes for the string reference (address).

So what needs to be done? You need to adorn your structure with a few attributes to tell the marshalling engine how to cope with it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=0)]
public struct MsgData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    private readonly int _value;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
    private readonly string _descr;

    ... rest as you have it
```

After doing this, you will get this size from `Marshal.SizeOf(...)`: 68.

68 = 4 bytes for the int + 64 for the string.

Note that when marshalling, dynamically sized results aren't really that easy to handle so setting an upper limit on the string is the way to go, for now.

---

**However**, there is a much easier solution to your problem, use the built in binary serialization in .NET.

Here are two new versions of your `Get*` methods that doesn't require you to do marshalling:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(MsgData message)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, message);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static MsgData GetMessage(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return (MsgData)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to apply the `SerializableAttribute` to your struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct MsgData
{
```

Comment: That last part was what I meant with "simple serialization" in this case. However I live and I learn. Thank you for the thorough and pedagogical explaination.